Can computer algebra system compute Galois group/splitting field of a polynomial over $p$-adic number field of higher degree?
I am looking for a computer algebra system that checks if the splitting fields of two polynomials over a $p$-number field are the same or not. At least, knowing their splitting fields are isomorphic will also give me an idea.
In PARI/GP, one can check the Galois of a polynomial upto degree $11$: for example,
P2 = x^9-x+1;
polgalois(P2)

which gives output %3 = [362880, -1, 34, "S9"] , that is, the Galois group is of order $362880$, signature $-1$, and the Galois group is isomorphic to $S_9$.
So given two polynomials up to degree $11$, one can check their Galois group and get some ideas if the splitting fields are equal by looking at their Galois groups.
But how to check the splitting fields/Galois groups of polynomials of degree greater than $11$ over the $p$-adic number field?
I found SageMath computing splitting fields of polynomials of degree more than $11$ over number fields.
However, I am looking for splitting fields or Galois groups over $p$-adic number fields.
Thanks

Have you tried Magma?

I think Magma is pretty good at these things. Beware though that most p-adic numbers do not have a name.

@Learner check this out http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/search?query=galois&chapters=1&examples=1&intrinsics=1&start=1

@DaveBenson, can you please tell me what actually it means by "$\text{most $p$-adic numbers do not have a name}$"?

@JorgeZuniga, I didn't use Magma. Can you give a sample code finding Galois group or splitting field of polynomials?

@JorgeZuniga, I think Magma computes Galois group of polynomials of degree less than $12$ as user manual mentioned in Chapter $5$. Also it is over number field. I am sure not how to use it over $p$-adic number field for polynomials of any degree

@Learner Well, it's just like real numbers - there are an uncountable number of $p$-adic numbers and a countable number of names. So you might want to represent $p$-adic numbers as approximations. But then the $2$-adic numbers $\pm\sqrt{-7}$ you might want to treat differently. So the question is, how do you want the computer to represent $p$-adic numbers?

@DaveBenson, thank you for the explanation. Indeed, I am used to both kinds of representation of $p$-adic number either through single element form like ordinary numbers you mentioned or through a sequence of numbers in $[0,p-1]$. However, I didn't understand why this is required in Magma regarding my question? It would be a nice to see a sample example using Magma answering my question
